# Capture Authentication failure in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've got below class to Authenticate users in a REST Service

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationService.class);

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public void getAuthentication(AccountCredentials credentials) {

        log.info("Authentication requested for user: " + credentials.getEmail());

        final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        credentials.getEmail(),
                        credentials.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }
}
```

The Authentication works fine but I would like to log every time there is a Authentication failure. The way it works now is that a `403` status is returned by default by Spring Security. How can I capture Authentication failures in a log? I've tried different ways but the code is never reached since after the `403` is returned there is no other code executed. I've also tried with a `try catch` block but that messes up the flow and I would have to code the `403` response. I like to keep the `403` status message and that no other code is run besides that it is captured in a log.

Comment: You are working around Spring Security instead I suggest integrating with it, that way you can also listen to the events emitted from Spring Security one of several [failure events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented it like this after reply from M. Deinum

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureListener
        implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFailureListener.class);

    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {

        log.info("Authentication failed for user: " + event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal());

    }
}
```

Works great. Just what is was looking for.